# Update user information 2 cases - with password and without password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an admin panel and would like to have two options for updating user information as an admin. One case when I want to update for example only user role and another case when I would like to update all information, including password in a case when user has forgot password.

RegisterModel.cs:

```
  public class RegisterModel
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserRoles { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
  }
```

AuthorizeController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
{
  ApplicationUser existingUser = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email))
  {
    IList<string> existingRoles = await this.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(existingUser);

    IdentityResult output = await this.UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(existingUser, existingRoles.FirstOrDefault());
    IdentityResult resultat = await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(existingUser, model.UserRoles);

    Collection<ApplicationUserRole> userRoles = new();
    userRoles.Add(new ApplicationUserRole { Name = model.UserRoles });

    existingUser.Email = model.Email;
    existingUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    existingUser.LastName = model.LastName;
    existingUser.ProfilePicture = model.ProfilePicture;
    existingUser.UserRoles = userRoles;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
    {
      existingUser.PasswordHash = this.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(existingUser, model.Password);
      existingUser.PasswordHash = this.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(existingUser, model.ConfirmPassword);
    }

    IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.UpdateAsync(existingUser);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
      var errors = result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description);

      return BadRequest(new RegisterResult { Successful = false, Errors = errors });
    }

    return Ok(new RegisterResult { Successful = true });
  }

  return NotFound("User not found!");
}
```

Currently I can't set RegisterModel.cs password fields as Required, because in this case I can't leave them empty. However I am using the same model for creation of new users and in this case they are required.
Also current code does necessary changes in DB, but I am getting an exception on:

```
IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.UpdateAsync(existingUser);
```

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: 'S' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'S' is an invalid start of a value.
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.  --->
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'S' is an invalid start of a
> value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader&
> json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[Blazing.Shared.RegisterResult,
> Blazing.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader,
> JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state,
> JsonReaderException ex)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[Blazing.Shared.RegisterResult, Blazing.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[RegisterResult](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[RegisterResult](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer,
> JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter
> converterBase)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[RegisterResult](ReadBufferState&
> bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack,
> JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.d__65`1[[Blazing.Shared.RegisterResult, Blazing.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__4`1[[Blazing.Shared.RegisterResult,
> Blazing.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()

Comment: Hi, if I didn't misunderstand your scenario, I think you need to write some business logic if you insist on using one user model for both creation and updating page. And you may debug the `UpdateAsync` method to figure out the issue or provide more code details to troubleshot your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you have a `new user creation page` and an `admin update user page` and they used the same user model, when creating a new user, password is necessary while it's not necessary when updating a user. So there're 2 ways in front of you.

Creating a new user model for the updating page. You know it's easy but I think your goal is not this when you choose to ask question here. So I think you have to add more business logic here.

For example, you can change the password property to not required, and require your create/update button's click event to check if this action requires entering a password, and in your backend code, you can also add judgement code about if this incoming request is a "password required" request and return error when not meeting the rule to avoid someone calling the backend controller directly. This way leaves the password required checking to your own code.

Another way is keeping the password still required, but now you need to write code for the "password not required" scenario. When your backend received a "password not required" request, it should query out the password from database first and add the password into the data model before the model validation so that it can also make the password "required".

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit([Bind("name,age,password")] UserModel user)
        {
            //password is required here 
            //if without the line-code below and the password is null here, it will return "password is required"
            user.password = "cccc";
            //Data validation
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

And based on your error message, I found [a blog shared similar issue](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2019/11/12/asp-net-core-api-s-is-an-invalid-start-of-a-value-path-linenumber-0-bytepositioninline-0/), so I think you need to check what data `UserManager.UpdateAsync` returned and if it is `IdentityResult`.